# Difference between error= and error=''

Tags: bash

In Bash is there a difference between these two variable definitions?

```
error=
error=''
```

Testing them on emptiness / being unset seems to suggest that they are equal but I still I would like to be sure.

Comment: No, there are no differences at all.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Why don't you answer that instead of adding a comment? I'm curious.

Comment: @Amarnasan I was lazy to give a more detailed answer than just a _there are no differences_. But you forced me to work a bit to give a fuller answer `:(`.

Comment: And you got 30 points! Yaaahooooo!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No, there are no differences at all.  *The quotes are stripped during parsing.*

---

From the [*Variable Assignment* section of the POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_22):

> In the shell command language, a word consisting of the following parts:
>
> ```
> varname=value
> ```

and a few lines below you'll see:

> If *value* is not specified, the variable shall be given a null value.

To check this (in Bash):

```
$ variable1=
$ variable2=''
$ declare -p variable{1,2}
declare -- variable1=""
declare -- variable2=""
```

they do look identical!

Comment: And the null value is identical to an empty string?

Comment: Quotes don't define a string; they simply escape all characters inside the string. The null value is just another name for the empty string, and `v1=''` and `v1=` are identical for the same reason `v1='foo'` and `v1=foo` (and `v1=\f\o\o`) are identical.